# Inner queries on a single table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table in my Oracle DB with data stored such as

```
ROLE_ID | USER_ID
------------------
 14     | USER A
 15     | USER A
 11     | USER B
 13     | USER A
 15     | USER B
 12     | USER C
 15     | USER C
```

I want to get all the `USER_ID`s which have `ROLE_ID` of both 13 and 15. Based on the example above, I should only get back `USER_A`.

If I write the query below

`select * from table where ROLE_ID in (13,15);` then I get other users as well.

How can I modify the query so that I only get back `USER A`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for having...

```
select user_id
  from my_table
 where role_id in (13,15)
 group by user_id.
having count(distinct role_id) = 2
```

You ensure, by using the distinct, that if there is say two USER A's that you still get one where it has both `role_id`s

Comment: This works great! thanks! but is there a way to have a NOT IN condition as well? For example, based on the example above, what if i want to put a condition of returning only the ids that have 13, 15 but don't have 14. Simply adding `AND role_id not in (14)` doesn't work..

Comment: I've asked a separate question on this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12169409/inner-queries-on-a-single-table-with-in-and-not-in-conditions

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
SELECT USER_ID FROM table WHERE ROLE_ID=13
        INTERSECT
SELECT USER_ID FROM table WHERE ROLE_ID=15
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with an inner join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.USER_ID
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 
 ON t2.USER_ID = t1.USER_ID 
 AND t2.ROLE_ID=15
WHERE t1.ROLE_ID=13
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do this in the HAVNIG clause only:

```
select user_id
from t
group by user_id
having max(case when role_id = 13 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and
       max(case when role_id = 15 then 1 else 0 end) = 1
```

I find that phrasing these conditions in the HAVING clause provides the most flexibility.  You can have "and" conditions, "or" conditions, limit the results to *only* users with 13 and 15, or whatever using the same basic construct.